# Display plm Model Results: Marginal Effects, p-Values for Interaction Terms, and Plots (Fixed Effects Method)

Tags: r, stargazer, plm, modelsummary, r-marginaleffects

I'm working with panel data using the plm package in R to estimate a fixed effects model that includes interaction terms. I'm currently able to get my model results using plm and display them with stargazer, but I'm looking for a more refined way to present these results, specifically focusing on the interaction terms. Additionally, I need to calculate and display the marginal effects of these interaction terms, including their p-values, in the same table. I'm also interested in plotting these marginal effects to better understand their impact.

Here's an example of my plm model setup:

```
fe_model_interaction <- plm(life_satisfaction ~ 
                                  employment_level_Full_Time*care_low +
                                  employment_level_Full_Time*care_high +

                                  employment_level_Part_Time*care_low +
                                  employment_level_Part_Time*care_high+
                             
                                  other_control_variables,
                                  data = data_analyse_mother, 
                                  index = c("pid", "syear"), 
                                  model = "within")
```

My questions are:

- What is the best way to display the plm model results, especially for interaction terms, in a more detailed and customizable format than what `stargazer` offers? I'm looking for a method to include standard errors, coefficients, and p-values in a clean and professional-looking table.
- How can I calculate and include the marginal effects of these interaction terms in the results table, along with their p-values?
- What are the recommended approaches or packages in R for plotting the marginal effects of interaction terms in a fixed effects model estimated with plm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `marginaleffects` and `modelsummary` both support `plm` objects. They both have extensive customization options and detailed tutorials. Please visit the package websites to access each package’s “Get Started” page:

- https://modelsummary.com
- https://marginaleffects.com

(Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

Your questions are not specific enough for me to solve your exact problem, but here is an example. First, we fit a model and display the results in a regression table using `modelsummary`:

```r
library(plm)
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

data("Produc", package = "plm")

mod <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) * log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
    data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"), model = "within")

modelsummary(mod)
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| log(pcap) | 0.033 |
|  | (0.074) |
| log(pc) | 0.348 |
|  | (0.069) |
| log(emp) | 0.763 |
|  | (0.031) |
| unemp | -0.005 |
|  | (0.001) |
| log(pcap) × log(pc) | -0.005 |
|  | (0.006) |
| Num.Obs. | 816 |
| R2 | 0.941 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.937 |
| AIC | 14092.6 |
| BIC | 14120.8 |
| RMSE | 0.04 |

Now, we use `marginaleffects` to compute quantities of interest. Note that the terminology around “marginal effects” is highly inconsistent across field, so I can’t know exactly what quantity you want based only on your post. Regardless, the package is extremely flexible, and you should be able to compute the quantities of interest if your read the documentation and tutorials. Here are some examples: average slopes, average contrasts, and average predictions by region:

```r
avg_slopes(mod)
# 
#   Term  Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)     S     2.5 %    97.5 %
#  emp    1.16e-03   4.66e-05 24.889   <0.001 451.8  1.07e-03  1.25e-03
#  pc     1.19e-05   1.05e-06 11.319   <0.001  96.3  9.81e-06  1.39e-05
#  pcap  -1.98e-06   2.77e-06 -0.712    0.476   1.1 -7.41e-06  3.46e-06
#  unemp -5.34e-03   9.89e-04 -5.393   <0.001  23.8 -7.27e-03 -3.40e-03
# 
# Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
# Type:  response

avg_comparisons(mod)
# 
#   Term Contrast  Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)     S     2.5 %    97.5 %
#  emp         +1  1.16e-03   4.66e-05 24.890   <0.001 451.9  1.07e-03  1.25e-03
#  pc          +1  1.19e-05   1.05e-06 11.324   <0.001  96.3  9.81e-06  1.39e-05
#  pcap        +1 -1.98e-06   2.77e-06 -0.712    0.476   1.1 -7.41e-06  3.46e-06
#  unemp       +1 -5.34e-03   9.90e-04 -5.390   <0.001  23.8 -7.28e-03 -3.40e-03
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
# Type:  response

avg_predictions(mod, by = "region")
# 
#  region Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#       1     9.72    0.01720  565   <0.001 Inf  9.68   9.75
#       2    11.90    0.02465  483   <0.001 Inf 11.85  11.95
#       3    11.53    0.01413  816   <0.001 Inf 11.50  11.55
#       4    10.12    0.00863 1173   <0.001 Inf 10.10  10.14
#       5    10.65    0.00480 2217   <0.001 Inf 10.64  10.66
#       6    10.58    0.00502 2109   <0.001 Inf 10.57  10.59
#       7    10.97    0.01094 1003   <0.001 Inf 10.95  10.99
#       8     9.61    0.01582  607   <0.001 Inf  9.58   9.64
#       9    11.23    0.01623  692   <0.001 Inf 11.19  11.26
# 
# Columns: region, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
# Type:  response
```

You can feed the resulting object back to `modelsummary` to display the results in a regression table. Here is an example:

```r
modelsummary(avg_slopes(mod))
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| emp | 0.001 |
|  | (0.000) |
| pc | 0.000 |
|  | (0.000) |
| pcap | 0.000 |
|  | (0.000) |
| unemp | -0.005 |
|  | (0.001) |
| Num.Obs. | 816 |
| R2 | 0.941 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.937 |
| AIC | 14092.6 |
| BIC | 14120.8 |
| RMSE | 0.04 |

And you can use the `modelsummary::modelplot()` function or one of the plotting functions from `marginaleffects` to visualize the results easily.

```r
modelplot(avg_slopes(mod))
```

[image]

```r
plot_predictions(mod, condition = c("pcap", "pc"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I was interested in calculating the marginal effects for the interaction terms of two dummy variables. 
So I tried `avg_slopes(mod)`but received an error message: > avg_slopes(mod)
Fehler in rbindlist(lo, fill = TRUE) : 
  Class attribute on column 7 of item 2 does not match with column 7 of item 1.

Do you know how to fix this?

Woul really appreciate your help.

Comment: I would need a minimal reproducible example to diagnose this.

Comment: After resolving an error in my plm model in R, I'm still struggling to calculate marginal effects and p-values for interaction terms between dummy variables (e.g., employment_Full_Time * care_intensity_low). The `avg_slopes(mod)` function doesn't seem to provide this information directly for the interaction terms.

How can I obtain the marginal effects and their p-values for these specific interaction terms in a plm model? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please read the marginal effects documentation and formulate a clearer question. "The marginal effect of an interaction" is not a well-understood standard statistical quantity. It could mean any number of things, as the terminology is very inconsistent across fields. If you specify clearly what mathematical quantity you are trying to estimate, I may be able to help (no guarantees). This vignette may be relevant, as it shows how to interpret the results from a model with interaction with dummies: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/experiments.html#x2-experiments

Comment: Thank you very much for your time& help.my model includes interaction terms between employment status and caregiving levels (low, moderate, high) all dummys.

In Stata, the inteff command is adept at calculating interaction effects directly for two variables, providing both the interaction effect and its significance. This command simplifies the process by directly outputting the interaction effect, which represents the change in the conditional probability that the outcome equals 1 for a change in one variable as the other variable changes. I'm seeking to replicate this functionality in R.

Comment: Just do: `avg_slopes(model, variables = "x", by = "z")`